# Why does Django ORM do operations on my timestamp field even if I didn't setup TIME_ZONE and USE_TZ in my settings.py

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

Django ORM seems to be converting my timestamp in a weird way and I'm not sure why.

Currently, our app doesn't have the settings **TIME_ZONE** and **USE_TZ**. There wasn't any need so far so we didn't use it.

Now, I'm trying to show some specific timestamp details while we don't have the settings mentioned above

The insert to the database (postgresql) works ok. the field that I'm using is *timestamp with time zone*. The timezone set in my local DB is "Asia/Singapore"

db value is: **"2022-07-01 23:09:14.253877+08"** which is correct.

Now, if I try to retrieve this value, what I get from the Django object is: **2022-07-01 10:09:14.253877.** which is totally of and not even close to UTC.

The timestamp value got converted to a different timezone (like for MST which is -7 from UTC). But it's actually not following any pattern since I also had some test data added at **1:11:00PM** but the stamp retrieved from the Django ORM is **00:11:28.848820**

To summarize, my question is how does Django ORM treat a timestamp value if **TIME_ZONE** and **USE_TZ** settings are not configured. I was naive to expect that it will retrieve the value as is from the database but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I didn't include any code because I wasn't doing any data manipulation on the retrieved Django objects. I'm just doing the simple Object.filter() but let me know if I'm missing any information that needs to be provided.

Comment: Django version, Postgres version?  Have you read [Time Zone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE)?

Comment: thanks for the link. I'll check that out. django version is 2.2, postgresql is 11.15

Comment: the global setting (used if nothing is defined in your project’s settings.py) remains 'America/Chicago'

Comment: So does that answer your question?